# How can i use Objective-C's Property feature in GNUstep?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I'm trying to use Objective-C 2.0 feature Property in GNUstep(using Windows).

But i can't use @property sign and @synthesize.

Although All of my codes are correct,compiler can't compile my property code.

Compiler also can't understand "@" sign.

Can i use Property feature in GNUstep.

If it's can use,Please tell me how can i do that?

Thanks you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GNUStep GCC compiler does not support `@property` (or any of the the other Objective-C 2.0 language changes). However, if you can use Clang, you have access to Objective-C 2.0 features at compilation. As long as you can find an Objective-C 2.0-compatible runtime, you're all set. See http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ#Which_Bits_of_Objective-C_2_Work.3F.

Comment: Newer GCC does support some of Objective-C 2.0 features. See http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html And it's GCC's Objective-C compiler, not GNUstep GCC compiler. But I'd go with Clang nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use Clang 3.3 + libobjc2 + GNUstep to compile all the current Objective-C 2.0 language features. (blocks/ARC/properties...)

But if you're on Windows, I think you may have some trouble to run Clang...

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is that out-of-the-box, you can't.  Version 2.0 of the language specification is specific to Apple's implementation.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C_2.0) for a summary.

Comment: It's specific to some additional implementations in foundation framework and the runtime, not Apple's.